# Show image exactly defined to a width

Tags: functions, post-content

I have a photoblog displaying posts as image galleries having width 500px and some posts as single image of width 900px. For posts with 900px width images, I made `category HQ`.

Posts with 500px width image galleries display fine. But those posts having single image doesn't display image of width 900px width instead 584px. E.g. Post content for 900px width image:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-15735" alt="Camping in the Rocky Mountains " src="http://abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Camping-in-the-Rocky-Mountains.jpg" width="900" height="700" />
```

Getting image info in browser shows 584px width. On further inspection, I came to know that there is a `$content_width variable` in `functions.php` set to 584px. I can't change it as I read it is for oEmbeds.

How to get this 900px width image to show as 900px width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$content_width` is the problem, you could set it to something different if you're viewing a single HQ post.

```
function wpse99587_single_hq_post() {
    global $post;
    if( is_single() && in_category( 'HQ', $post->ID ) ){
        global $content_width;
        $content_width = 900;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse99587_single_hq_post' );
    // I dithered on where to hook this function;
    // if there's a better hook to use, please correct me
```

This assumes that the `$content_width` variable is global.

See the Codex pages for [`is_single()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) & [`in_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Pat's answer above. Try to add this to your CSS.

```
img {
     width:100%;
    }
```

Sometimes thats all it takes